# Get Django object attributes from url to use as context

Tags: django

I filtered a list and sent a link from the chosen record to my view.

I want to use the attributes of that object as context to filter some models.

I tried this code:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    entity = self.entity
    context["entity"] = entity

    ... # using entity as a filter 
    (e.g. if Model.objects.filter(entity=entity):
    conditions)
    
    return context
```

This raises the error: 'EffectivenessProcessOwner' object has no attribute 'entity'

The local variables reflected are:

```
Variable    Value
__class__   <class 'internalcontrol.views.EffectivenessProcessOwner'>
context     {'pk': 1,
            'view': <internalcontrol.views.EffectivenessProcessOwner object at 
            0x00000284A5672040>}
kwargs      {'pk': 1}
self        <internalcontrol.views.EffectivenessProcessOwner object at 
            0x00000284A5672040>
```

How do I get the entity attribute (and others) from the object?

Added:

[This is where the link comes from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwF0x.png)

I am new in Django but I think this should be easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data):

> `object`: The object that this view is displaying (`self.object`).

So what you are looking for is `self.object.entity`.

Comment: Thanks, Selcuk, for the prompt response. Unfortunately I then get this error: 'EffectivenessProcessOwner' object has no attribute 'object'.

Comment: What generic view class are you extending? Can you post the whole view?

Comment: The image is of a filtered list view. Am using CBVs. The view receiving the link (the one with the shown code) is a template view.

Comment: Thanks for persevering with a newbie. I don't think the whole view would help. For one it is too big. What matters is when I do the filtering manually it renders almost perfectly. Almost because then I catch the first occurrence of the entity from the list. The link captures the specific object I want other attributes from.